# No entry sign on MacBook pro when installing snow leopard from 'new' disc onto new HD

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard

My HD died on my MacBook pro so I decided to change the HD myself. I didn't have the original snow leopard disc so got a copy from a friend. When I try to boot from disc (holding c) is runs the DVD drive, followed by apple symbol. After a short while, the apple symbol is replaced by a no entry symbol. Totally at a loss as to what to do. Tried different copies of the copied disc, but same issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Is your friend's Snow Leopard disk one he got with a Mac, or one he purchased at retail?

Disks that came with Macs are hardware-specific, if it came from a different model/revision than your MacBook Pro, then it likely won't work.

Try your install with a retail disk (or a [Lion/Mountain Lion installer on USB](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/07/25/create-a-bootable-mountain-lion-usb-key-installer/)) and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the disk that was shipped with your MacBook or atleast the orginal  OSX disk for the same model.

Answer (score -1):

Was your machine delivered with Snow Leopard? Apple made Lion and Mountain Lion machines either incompatible with, or block the installation of Snow Leopard - even refurbs that once could have run SL.

Comment: This is not always true, and especially not so with refurbished systems. This generally only applies to new hardware refreshes that occur after a new OS has been released.

Comment: Correct but it is a possibility worth considering.

Comment: Reconsidering my previous comment: I recall inquiring about refurbed iMacs offered with 10.7+ that would, in their day, have been 10.6 capable, but which Apple Tech Support confirmed to me on the phone could no longer be downgraded. Their specific advice was, "If it is delivered with Lion/Mountain Lion, it would no longer be compatible with Snow Leopard."

Comment: Yes, that is the official Apple response. Any system made after a new OS release officially only supports the new OS or later. However, from my experience as an Apple sales rep, I have first-hand accounts of such systems often being downgradable still.

Comment: Good to know - I needed a SL-capable machine (Apple refurb) and watched the refurb store for the occasional ones that would be delivered w/SL. Are they downgradeable simply by installing SL or do they need something else to enable it?

Comment: If it will work, it will work with a simple wipe and install from SL media. However, again, I can't guarantee it will work, just that I've seen it work in many cases. If Apple did in fact flash a firmware chip there is always a chance of it no longer working.

Comment: What they told me was that the hardware would have been modified on a L or ML machine and not to expect it to accept SL anymore. Always worth testing on a machine in hand, but I probably wouldn't buy and count on it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't blame you. For accounts I managed while working at Apple, I always allowed them a one-month return period, but I would never count on that personally. :)